# Error during parsing of Atom response

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, atom-feed, yandex

I try to parse a HttpWebRequest from Yandex-Fotki (Image Hoster). I get a response in Atom-Format, but in SyndicationFeed I get an error: **The element with name 'service' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2007/app' is not an allowed feed format.**

My Code is:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(response));
            SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
```

Here is the input(response from the site):

```
<app:service xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <app:workspace>
    <atom:title>packda на Яндекс.Фотках</atom:title>
    <app:collection href="http://api-fotki.yandex.ru/api/users/packda/albums/" id="album-list">
      <atom:title>Все альбомы пользователя packda</atom:title>
      <app:accept>application/atom+xml; type=entry, application/json; type=entry</app:accept>
    </app:collection>
    <app:collection href="http://api-fotki.yandex.ru/api/users/packda/photos/" id="photo-list">
      <atom:title>Все фотографии пользователя packda</atom:title>
      <app:accept>image/*</app:accept>
      <app:categories scheme="http://api-fotki.yandex.ru/api/users/packda/tags/" />
    </app:collection>
    <app:collection href="http://api-fotki.yandex.ru/api/users/packda/tags/" id="tag-list">
      <atom:title>Все теги пользователя packda</atom:title>
      <app:accept />
    </app:collection>
  </app:workspace>
</app:service>
```

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SyndicationFeed` will only parse XML with [Atom](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287) or [RSS](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) Syndication Format. The response of the site Yandex-Fotki doesn't seem to be neither.

Ok, I found a thing that maybe it is what you are looking for. If you do a request in your webbrowser of a `<collection href="http://api...">` value you get a XML in Atom Syndication format.

[image]

This is the XML you have to parse with `SyndicationFeed`. So, you have to retrieve the href value of collection elements, get that XML and load it in SyndicationFeed. To retireve the collection elements you can try:

Read DOM with XMLReader OR Deserilize it to a custom class OR Load XML into a DataSet OR LINQ to XML.

Comment: Is it possible to parse this file like a xml file or I have to get each Element with XDocumen/XElement ?

Comment: Yes. I think it is possibile.